# Make pairs of labels and nested lists

Tags: python, list, nested

Given list of lists as follows:

```
total = [['ford', 'x', 'z', 'A', 'sedan', ['steering wheel problems', 'gearbox problems', 'broken engine']], ['fiat', 'y', 'x', 'C', 'kombi', ['steering wheel problems']], ...]
```

And list of fields:

```
labels = ['make', 'model', 'version', 'type', 'infos']
```

I need to create object like:

```
x = [[['make': ford, 'model': 'x', 'version': 'x', 'type': 'z', 'infos': ['steering wheel problems']], ['make': fiat, 'model': 'x', 'version': 'x', 'type': 'z', 'infos': ['steering wheel problems', 'gearbox problems']], ...]
```

How to create such thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dict()` can take a list of 2-tuples as an argument, and we can construct one of those easily by using `zip()`.

If we can add an extra label to account for the `'sedan'` entry, the code becomes much more concise:

```
labels = ['make', 'model', 'version', 'type', 'body', 'infos']
x = [
    dict(zip(labels, entry))
    for entry in total
]
# [
#  {'make': 'ford', 'model': 'x', 'version': 'z', 'type': 'A', 'body': 'sedan', 'infos': ['steering wheel problems', 'gearbox problems', 'broken engine']}, 
#  {'make': 'fiat', 'model': 'y', 'version': 'x', 'type': 'C', 'body': 'kombi', 'infos': ['steering wheel problems']}
# ]
```

Otherwise, we have to manually 'edit out' that item from the list. The most succinct way is probably this:

```
labels = ['make', 'model', 'version', 'type', 'infos']
x = [
    dict(zip(labels, entry[:4] + entry[5:]))
    for entry in total
]
# [
#  {'make': 'ford', 'model': 'x', 'version': 'z', 'type': 'A', 'infos': ['steering wheel problems', 'gearbox problems', 'broken engine']}, 
#  {'make': 'fiat', 'model': 'y', 'version': 'x', 'type': 'C', 'infos': ['steering wheel problems']}
# ]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
total = [['ford', 'x', 'z', 'A', ['steering wheel problems', 'gearbox problems', 'broken engine']], ['fiat', 'y', 'x', 'C', ['steering wheel problems']]]
labels = ['make', 'model', 'version', 'type', 'infos']

new= [dict(zip(labels,x)) for x in total ]
print(new)
```

output:

```
[{'make': 'ford', 'model': 'x', 'version': 'z', 'type': 'A', 'infos': ['steering wheel problems', 'gearbox problems', 'broken engine']}, {'make': 'fiat', 'model': 'y', 'version': 'x', 'type': 'C', 'infos': ['steering wheel problems']}]
```